# Python не работает метод np.T при обращении через переменную

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-3.6, tuple

есть следующий код:

```
import numpy as np
X = ((1,10),(1,7),(1,12))
step = np.dot(X.T,X)
```

но метод X.T не работает и вываливает ошибку

> step1 = np.dot(X.T,X) Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "", line 1, in  AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no
>   attribute 'T'

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: У тупла нет атрибута `T`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как указано в сообщении об ошике, у объекта `tuple` нет атрибута `.T`. Такой атрибут есть у `numpy.ndarray`, поэтому создайте `NDArray`:

```
In [17]: X = np.array(((1,10),(1,7),(1,12)))

In [18]: np.dot(X.T, X)
Out[18]:
array([[  3,  29],
       [ 29, 293]])
```

Альтернативное решение c использованием `tuple`:

```
In [21]: X = ((1,10),(1,7),(1,12))

In [22]: np.dot(np.transpose(X), X)
Out[22]:
array([[  3,  29],
       [ 29, 293]])
```

Еще несколько решений в стиле `Numpy`:

```
In [27]: X = np.array(((1,10),(1,7),(1,12)))

In [28]: X.T @ X
Out[28]:
array([[  3,  29],
       [ 29, 293]])

In [29]: X.T.dot(X)
Out[29]:
array([[  3,  29],
       [ 29, 293]])
```